# Credit card charging for Authorize.Net depending on address

Tags: payment, credit-card, authorize.net

I have a sign up form for my site where users enter the following address fields

1. state
2. country
3. zipcode

This entering of information was done only for united states and its states I let users sign up using a credit card with Authorize.Net. We now have to change the field names

1. state to state/province
2. country field now takes international countries as values
3. zipcode to zipcode/postcode

Will this change of fields and their subsequent entering of values by the users coming to the site, change the charging by authorize.net? Could you also provide me the link to the solution of any forum or support on Authorize.Net if it exists?

Answer (score 0):

Authorize.Net isn't the one who will have issues with you accepting orders outside of the US. It's the merchant account provider who will. Authorize.Net's fees (monthly and per transaction) will remain the same regardless of where the transaction originates.

The merchant account provider will have issues with international orders, though. International orders are higher risk then domestic orders and if they start to comprise a significant portion of your transactions you may find yourself being reviewed by your merchant account provider. It is possible that they may prohibit you from accepting these orders. You should contact them *before* you start to accept international orders to find out what their policy is pertaining to foreign orders.